# Attemp to access WAMP server from other devices on network gives 403 forbidden

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6, wamp

I set up a WAMP server on my main PC. I have files in the `www` directory, and can see the results via `localhost`.

The problem is, I am not able to access the server via the server IP from even the local machine much less other devices within wifi range. I would like to be able to view files (or projects) on WAMP server from other devices within LAN.

I have tried the following:

Edited `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` to:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.8/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I will change this to something more secure once I can access the server from all local devices.

Checked my router settings (Comcast modem/router). It is currently set to allow LAN to WAN for all devices.

ran `ipconfig` in `cmd` prompt. These are the results without ipv6

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\agl19_000>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.6
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::ba9b:c9ff:fec1:e082%3
                                       10.0.0.1

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.wa.comcast.net.

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I have tried using `10.0.0.6` and am getting 403 forbidden. The other visible IP is for the router.

Comment: Firewall status?

Comment: Port 80 is not blocked by my machines firewall. Specifically set rules.

Comment: Hehe. No encrypted addresses, just IPv6 addresses :-)  Good to see that Comcast is doing its job and provides IPv6 to its customers!

Comment: @HelloWorld Please see [cheat sheet for comment formatting](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).